# location of MAC Vendor file on a Mac

Tags: macos, arp

where is the vendor file located on a mac? I have some ARP related code that is trying to lookup vendor info and it just stalls. I'm looking for help with the code, I just want to track down the file. thanks

Comment: Why do you think macOS has such a file?

Comment: from the articles I have read  it seemed that it would be part of a standard linux install. Obviously I am mistaken.